# how to configure sonarlint in VScode for C language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, sonarlint-vs

I'm practising clean code and I installed sonarlint as a static testing tool to help me write clean code. after installing the editor rises this notification

> SonarLint is unable to analyze C and C++ file(s) because there is no configured compilation
> database.

after some searching, I found that I should  add a file with a name

> compile_commands.json.

this file should be exported automatically by cmake after adding this option

> CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS

where can I add this option in VScode.

[this link is where the vscode redirected me to creat the required .json file](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-vscode/wiki/C-and-CPP-Analysis)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you invoke the cmake configure command via vs code, it automatically requests this to be set as a cache variable via command-line. look under your binary directory for the file.

Comment: Also, from [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html): "_Note: This option is implemented only by Makefile Generators and the Ninja. It is ignored on other generators._". Are you using one of the supported generators? Ex. Visual Studio doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using CMake for your build. If that is the case then add the following line to the CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

Then build the project and the database will be created for you.